# Redirrection in .htaccess to set Semantic URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set [Semantic URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL) via .htaccess (on local server). I've already replaced index.php?id=# with page# by the means of:

```
RewriteRule ^/?page([0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1
```

It is working. That means that .htaccess is connected properly and runs. Now I want to "glue" the produced link with the original one. That is, to redirect from index.php?id=# on page#. Can't deal with it.

For example, I take only the page with id=0 and make this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.loc\/index\.php?id=0$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.loc/page0$1 [R=301,L]
```

Tell me, please, what is wrong with the rows above.

Comment: `%{HTTP_HOST}` really just contains the vhost name, not the URL path. You'd want to match `QUERY_STRING` and/or the `REQUEST_URI` per RewriteRule simply.

Comment: I've tried also something like this: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://site.loc/page%1? [R=301,L]. Didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/31280108/345031 on "Ping-Pong" rewrites and how to enable the `RewriteLog` (or compare access/error.log) to debug such issues.

Your approach was on the right track. But I think for the old-to-new URL redirects you should cut it down to:

```
                                optional   escape \?
                                   ↓         ↓
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(?:index\.php)?\?id=(\d+)$
RewriteRule .* http://example.org/page%1 [R,END]
                                             ↑
                                      Safer than [L] flag
```

The `REQUEST_URI` contains the `?`-separated `QUERY_STRING` already. So the RewriteCond can match both. It's best to optionalize the `index.php` there, because that's not part of the incoming request URL.

(Capturing the page=id parameter per `\d+` and `%1` was already correct.)

Just use the `[END]` flag for both Ping-Pong rules. Make your existing internal/pretty-URL RewriteRule last. Otherwise they'd likely interact.

Comment: Didn't help a lot. But thank you anyway. I think, I need some additional PHP here,

Comment: You could send the redirect easily in the PHP handler of course. Detecting the "old" incoming path works similarily. Otherwise, look at the logs, or describe the observed behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?id=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule page%1? [NC,R,L]
RewriteRule ^/?page([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```